# How to get the InnerHTML of a div in C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project when I need to copy the innerHTML of a div and send it to a txt file in C#. While I can get the innerHTML of the entire page through this code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("youtube.com");
            textBox1.Text = htmlCode;
        }

    }
```

What do I need to do to get the innerHTML of a specific div?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for this using HtmlAgilityPack...

1. Install HtmlAgilityPack from NuGet.
2. Use this code.

   ```
   HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
   HtmlDocument dc = web.Load("Your_Url");
   var s = dc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='div_id']").InnerHtml;
   ```

It will return inner html of div.

Comment: Thank you! but I get an error that the"HtmlDocument" is an ambiguous reference between (System.windows.forms.HtmlDocument) and (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument). Would you please tell me how to handle this error?

Comment: remove this System.windows.forms.HtmlDocument @Ibra